# Using an older version of a library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6

I am porting an application from VB6 to VB.NET. The older application uses Graphic Server 5 for generating an extrapolated graph. But I am unable to use the same library in VB.NET. I am porting the older application to a Windows Forms Application. I have added the reference to the library to my project and added the graph control to the toolbox. When I try to drag drop the control from the toolbox onto a form, I get an error "Failed to import the ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered."

So I registered the ocx file and tried again. But it's of no use. I browsed some sites and found that it is because of Visual Studio is not able to generate the wrapper classes required for the library. I also read that the problem can be solved by adding the wrapper classes which are generated at run time manually.

I changed the target framework from 4.0 to 3.5. Now I am able to add the control to the form. Once the control is added, the IDE crashes.

Can someone help me out? I don't have the option of using another tool.

Comment: You are using an ancient 3rd party component.  The vendor no longer sells nor supports it.  You'll need to move on and scratch the idea that you can continue using it.

Comment: I know ancient is the right word. But the customer has requested that we use the same one. I am looking at other options too. But any help with this will at add to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test purposes only drive targetting dotnet 2.0. Have had the same problem, but I actually moved to VS 2005 and am able to import the OCX I needed. You might give that a try. This is a known issue with VS2010